# Permission Settings: Anonymous Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I've never seen this before. Our global and site level settings are 'don't allow sharing outside your organization' but today I noticed in the Site Permissions page an entry for Anonymous Users. It is not clickable and each time I check the box, it checks all other boxes. Does it impact our global settings? Or, how do I remove this permission?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the issue occur in SharePoint online?

If so, I suggest you could remove the “Anonymous Users” from server end.
You could submit a service request like the picture below.

[image]

There is a similar post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba9c26c7-b58e-42fc-95c4-1bb9399f8f53/remove-anonymous-user-access?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Yes, its SharePoint Online and thanks for the link. I submitted a ticket.