# Anonymous User in Site Permission

Tags: sharepoint-online

On my company's SharePoint site (using SharePoint Online), in the permissions section there is a line stating Anonymous Users with a permission level of Entire Web site.

[image]
Can someone explain to me:

- What this is,
- Why is it there, and
- How do I get rid of it?

This is in the top level site, I have 8 subsites representing the company departments, 7 of which do not show this Anonymous Users permission, 1 does which I would like to remove.  The site should only be viewable by company employees (using 356 Business Essentials subscription).

Employees should still be allowed to share documents from libraries to people outside the company.

I've have tried going through [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba9c26c7-b58e-42fc-95c4-1bb9399f8f53/remove-anonymous-user-access?forum=sharepointadmin) where it is advised to disable guest links at the site collection, but I cannot see this option.

Comment: Similar issue here you can find here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240519/permission-settings-anonymous-users

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest looking over this [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37346.sharepoint-online-how-to-grant-anonymous-access-to-site-collection-or-site-page.aspx) for better insight into configuring and managing Anonymous Access in SharePoint Online environments. It covers both global and site collection level settings.

Cheers,

-Drew